# Most efficient ways to select WebService based on parameter

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I currently have an ASP.NET `WebService1.asmx`.

This uses `SqlConnection` to talk to Sql Server.

I have now created `WebServiceDB2.asmx` which uses `OdbcConnection`.

I will be passing in a parameter from the front end to determine which service I use.

So for instance, in the code behind this is how I would make a regular web service call-

```
protected void deleteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        WebService1 ws = new WebService1();
        ws.deleteTerm(term); 
    }
```

My question being is there a more efficient way of implementing the option of the `DB2` call than this -

```
protected void deleteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(parameter == "SQL")
        { 
             WebService1 ws = new WebService1();
             ws.deleteTerm(term);
        }
        if(parameter == "DB2")
        { 
             WebServiceDB2 ws = new WebServiceDB2();
             ws.deleteTerm(term);
        } 
    }
```

As this will double my code and I make web service calls regularly in all pages of the site.

Comment: An aside: when creating a new service, why not use WCF? ASMX services are deprecated.

Comment: If the services will provide the same operations, isn't it a better idea to keep just one service which passes the parameter all the way down to the database operations layer, where the appropriate connection will be used?

Comment: The only thing is the SQL for both SQL server and DB2 varies, so I am stuck with either having one webservice with varying methods or two webservices with varying calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can extract this check in a method in your project, which takes the parameter for the server as well.

```
public void DeleteTerm(string term, string Server)
{
   if(Server == "SQL")
    { 
         WebService1 ws = new WebService1();
         ws.deleteTerm(term);
    }
    if(Server == "DB2")
    { 
         WebServiceDB2 ws = new WebServiceDB2();
         ws.deleteTerm(term);
    } 
}
```

Then later you can call it like:

```
protected void deleteButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    DeleteTerm(term,paramter);//where parameter is your class level variable. 
}
```